# React Native: calling an existing function in a react-native-webview using injectJavascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

The following is my use-case:

There is an existing web app (say `https://example.com`). It has some functions in modules that are called on load of the page. For example:

```
// index.js
import * as test from "./test.js";
```

The test.js has  its functions

```
// test.js
const check = () => {
   alert("check called");
}

export { check }
```

Now from the React Native side I wish to call the `check` function using injectJavascript. The App.js looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.webviewRef = null;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignContent: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
          <Button
            title="Check"
            onPress={() => {
              const clientResponseCode = `
                 test.check();     
                 true;
             `;
              this.webviewRef.injectJavaScript(clientResponseCode);
            }}
          />
        </View>
        <WebView
          source={{ uri: 'https://example.com' }}
          ref={ref => this.webviewRef = ref}
          javaScriptEnabled={true}
          onMessage={this.onMessage}
        />
      </>
    );
  }
}

//make this component available to the app
export default App;
```

What **works** inside clientResponseCode:

1. `document.querySelector("#any-id").innerHTML = "....";`

What **does not work** inside clientResponseCode:

2. `test.check();`
3. `document.test.check();`
4. `window.test.check();`

I also tried to to use the postMessage method with addEventListener on the web side but it does not get invoked. I tried both these below options.

5. `window.postMessage("hello");`
6. `windows.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage("hello");`

What will be the way to invoke the **check method** from the **test module** that is **imported in index.js** on the website?

Or is it that only the DOM is available to App.js and only dynamically loading of javascript code is permitted? If so, then I will create some webcomponent to inject the dynamic passing of objects (blob, in my case) to the DOM.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

The following seemed to have worked.

In index.js on the web side

```
//index.js

..
..
// add the following
window.check = test.check; // without brackets
...
```

on the React App side

```
// App.js
...
...
    const clientResponseCode = `
       window.check();      
       true;
     `;
              
     this.webviewRef.injectJavaScript(clientResponseCode);
```

It is possible to pass parameters too to the check function